# how to save user's profile pic in facebook using php

Tags: php, facebook

Hi I m trying to create app that uses user's profile pic in it. So I write code that reads profile pic from facebook and save it on my server. I use following code

```
function GetImageFromUrl($link){
   $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$userpicpath = "http://graph.facebook.com/$uid/picture?type=normal";

$sourcecode = GetImageFromUrl($userpicpath);
$savefile = fopen("$uid-normal.jpg", "w"); //this is name of new file that i save
fwrite($savefile, $sourcecode);
fclose($savefile);
```

Here $uid is id of user.

The above code doesn't work properly.

But when I copy the $userpicpath(ie http://graph.facebook.com/$uid/picture?type=normal) in browser and press enter it will return me new path to image in address bar and shows me proper image that I want. If i passed this new path in address bar to my function it saves image file that I want.

Why this is happening? How i get that second image path and pass it to my function in program. Please Help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook uses a redirect to allow for easy embedding on websites. It accomplishes this by sending a HTTP 302 redirect header. Since I see you are using a CURL, I have written my example based on a guide I have found online. I also posted how to send the user agent via cURL. Here's my getFBResponse() function for you, and can be used to replace $userpicpath's assignment. Try this: $userpicpath = getFBRedirect();

```
// Only calling the head
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // header will be at output
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD'); // HTTP request is 'HEAD'

$content = curl_exec ($ch);

// The response should be:
/*
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
*/
// So splitting on "Location: " should give an array of index 2, the URL you want being the second index (1)
$theUrl = split($content, "Location: ");
return $content[1];
```

}

Comment: This solution will be very fragile if, for example, the `Location:` header is not the last line of the response (perfectly possible). Much better to let the CURL library parse the headers properly, and as mentioned below, it can even follow the redirect for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the User-Agent header for your request. FB and many other services often refuse to serve request with no User-Agent set.

**EDIT:** It can be done like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-Agent: AnythingYouLikeHere'));
```

**EDIT 2:** The part about redirects is also true. To let cURL automatically take care of redirect handling, you can do this:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
```

Comment: @user392406: Updated, see example above.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a redirection. Those can not be handled by PHP, you'll need to find out the real address of the picture to use `GetImageFromUrl`

Answer (score 0):

You can tell CURL to follow the redirect returned by the Facebook server by setting the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option; the below should work as desired:

```
function GetImageFromUrl($link) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    # ADDED LINE:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```