# Save facebook profile image using cURL

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I'm trying to save a users profile image on facebook using CURL. When I use the code below, I save a jpeg image but it has zero bytes in it. But if I exchange the url value to https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/211398_812269356_2295463_n.jpg, which is where http://graph.facebook.com/' . $user_id . '/picture?type=large redirects the browser, the image is saved without a problem. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php

$url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $user_id . '/picture?type=large';


$file_handler = fopen('pic_facebook.jpg', 'w');
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file_handler);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
fclose($file_handler);
```

?>

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429964/how-to-save-users-profile-pic-in-facebook-using-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a redirect, so you have to add this option for curl

```
// safemode if off:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

but if you have safemode if on, then:

```
// safemode if on:
<?php
function curl_redir_exec($ch)
    {
        static $curl_loops = 0;
        static $curl_max_loops = 20;
        if ($curl_loops++ >= $curl_max_loops)
        {
            $curl_loops = 0;
            return FALSE;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        @list($header, $data) = @explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302)
        {
            $matches = array();
            preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
            $url = @parse_url(trim(array_pop($matches)));
            if (!$url)
            {
                //couldn't process the url to redirect to
                $curl_loops = 0;
                return $data;
            }
            $last_url = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
            if (!$url['scheme'])
                $url['scheme'] = $last_url['scheme'];
            if (!$url['host'])
                $url['host'] = $last_url['host'];
            if (!$url['path'])
                $url['path'] = $last_url['path'];
            $new_url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'] . (@$url['query']?'?'.$url['query']:'');
            return $new_url;
        } else {
            $curl_loops=0;
            return $data;
        }
    }

    function get_right_url($url) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        return curl_redir_exec($curl);
    }


    $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $user_id . '/picture?type=large';

    $file_handler = fopen('pic_facebook.jpg', 'w');
    $curl = curl_init(get_right_url($url));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file_handler);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($file_handler);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Hovwewer, It does not seem to work for me. It's probably me screwing something up. I get this error: Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /home/web81206/domains/utvecklingtesttco.se/public_html/fb/index.php on line 83

Any suggestions?

Comment: darn. try this function instead: http://au.php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-setopt.php#71313

Comment: Nope, can't get this to work, it's a quite simple thing that I want to do, and yet I don't seem to find anyd valid code. What a strange thing! Thank's anyway for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you can't process the redirect, try this instead:

Make the request to `https://graph.facebook.com/<USER ID>?fields=picture` and parse the response, which will be in JSON format and look like this - e.g. for [Zuck](https://graph.facebook.com/4?fields=picture) you get this response:

```
{
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/157340_4_3955636_q.jpg"
}
```

Then make your curl request directly to retrieve the image from that cloud storage URL

Comment: Good thinking, I will try this solution also, even though I was given another nice solution by @deadrunk

Answer (score 1):

set

`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`  to true

so that it follows the 301/302 redirect the reads the image file from final location.
i.e.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Hovwewer, It does not seem to work for me. It's probably me screwing something up. I get this error: Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /home/web81206/domains/utvecklingtesttco.se/public_html/fb/index.php on line 83

Comment: try using `file_get_contents` instead, which will do this part automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it this way, works perfectly fine:

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/[App-Scoped-ID]/picture?width=378&height=378&access_token=[Access-Token]');
$file = fopen('fbphoto.jpg', 'w+');
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

You just need an App Access Token (APPID . '|' . APPSECRET), and you can specify width and height.

You can also add "redirect=false" to the URL, to get a JSON object with the URL (For example: https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1...)

`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` has been removed in PHP5.4, so it´s not really an option anymore.

Comment: With this I get "https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0"

Comment: this might be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952204/warning-file-get-contents-https-wrapper-is-disabled-in-the-server-configu