# How to save Facebook profile image by image url provided by Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I have used following code to save the facebook profile pic by url provided by facebbok

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/[App-Scoped-ID]/picture?width=378&height=378&access_token=[Access-Token]');
$file = fopen('fblogo/fbphoto.jpg', 'w+');
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

The image saved on desired place but it saved by 0 byte means corrupt, please let know how to save the image properly

Answer (score 1):

This looks like my answer from this thread: [Save facebook profile image using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680676/save-facebook-profile-image-using-curl/26350397#26350397)

Try adding redirect=false to the API call to get the real location of the picture. And if that does not work, try with CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $app_scoped_id . '/picture?width=378&height=378&redirect=false&access_token=xxx');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($data);
```

This will get the real URL, and you can use another call to get the image:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $data->data->url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And if that does not work either, make sure your provider supports CURL requests :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
$image = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$data[id]/picture?width=800&height=600&redirect=false"),true);
$image = file_get_contents($image['data']['url']);
file_put_contents("desired_filename.jpg",$image);
```