# Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by all

Tags: php

When I am upload a csv file with zipcode it will convert and save a latitude and logitude. The error occurring a convert a zipcode to lat,lng. In my localhost its working fine. When I am uploading in a live server. I am getting this error **Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /hermes/bosnaweb05a/b1410/ipg.rwdinfotechcom/vw/zipmapping/index.php on line 29** . I have checked my google api key also. I can't able add php.ini file. If I upload php.ini file its shows internal server error.

```html
Here my code
function getLnt($zip){
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyDEGgYDar8y3Bx-1FpY3hq6ON4LufoRK60&address=
".urlencode($zip)."&sensor=false";

$result_string = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result_string, true);

$result1[]=$result['results'][0];
$result2[]=$result1[0]['geometry'];
$result3[]=$result2[0]['location'];
return $result3[0];
}
```

Comment: Better show us your php.INI instead the code.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First, check your PHP file with this code and then enable the fopen in your php.ini file

```
<?php 
if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
    die('allow_url_fopen is enabled. file_get_contents should work well');
} else {
    die('allow_url_fopen is disabled. file_get_contents would not work');
}

?>
```

Edit the php.ini file and enable using below code

```
allow_url_fopen = 1 //0 for Off and 1 for On Flag
```

Comment: I have removed the reference to [the "allow_url_include" setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) from this answer; it is needed much more rarely, and has a whole bunch of extra security implications which need to be understood. It is **not** necessary for use with `file_get_contents` and similar functions.

Comment: ini_get returns "off" = condition is true for both results

Answer (score 47):

1. Login to your Cpanel
2. Under Software click on **MultiPHP INI Editor**
   [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqxx4.png)
3. Click on **Editor Mode** and select Domain
   [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDga3.png)
4. Paste **allow_url_fopen = 1** and save

Comment: I did this but am still getting the same message. Is there another step that needs to be completed before it will work?

Comment: @primehalo go to WHM > MultiPHP INI Editor > select PHP version and set allow_url_fopen to Enabled.

Comment: @WHM Mine doesn't have that option available

Comment: In my cPanel there is a checkbox to enable `allow_url_fopen` in (Software)Select PHP Version > Options(tab at the top), although if this doesn't solve it for you see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64280073/5519644).

Comment: Use cUrl instead of file_get_contents.

Comment: This headed me in a right direction, but my solution was a little different. I had to click `Use PHP Selector` for my domain in question, and then set PHP version to 8.1

Answer (score 21):

This solution worked for me as I couldn't access the php.ini file.

I added this function:

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
{
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    if ($contents) return $contents;
    else return FALSE;
}
```

and use it instead of

> file_get_contents($url)

and it worked.

The solution is better explained [here](https://5balloons.info/fix-file_get_contents-disabled-error-php/), all credits to the creator of the post.

Comment: This is better as most of the servers have the limits n PHP.INI file. So this works great. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I don't have access to the php.ini file. Then it's a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Try removing the lines below from .htaccess and switch to the latest version of PHP.**

For me this was being caused by the following getting added to .htaccess:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php70___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Removing it solved the problem but it reappeared after an unknown period of time.

I noticed I was running (deprecated) PHP 7.0 and I changed it to (latest version) 7.4. I sent a support ticket to our hosting provider about the problem and they responded with:

> If you've selected PHP 7.4 now, it shouldn't replace those lines any
> longer, as that's what CloudLinux does - it forces the specific PHP
> version to be loaded via .htaccess

It's not come back in the last hour so fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I google this topic.
I could not update it from joomla direct 3.9.1 to 3.9.2 not even by uploading manually.
The reason was that before this update it forced me to upgrade php version to 7.2 so I did it from cpanel, now to solve next update will be this:

1. Login to cpanel
2. Find " MultiPHP INI Editor" under software
3. Choose your domain and select edit
4. Set :
   "max_execution_time " to 90 (it was in mine 30)
   "memory_limit" to 256M (it was by new php enabling 32M only !)
   "post_max_size" to 100M
   "upload_max_filesize" to 100M

...because every php new version is set to default.

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

if need only once run script using CLI then just add -d allow_url_fopen=1, even if it disabled in main php.ini, example:

```
php -d allow_url_fopen=1 script.php
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the Code below to your PHP File:

```
<?php
    ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
```

The Problem could probably be that on the Server, the PHP Setting for allow_url_fopen may have been configured differently: 0 for example. You could also do the same in your php.ini File if you have access to it.

Hope this helps....

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` can **NOT** be changed *in-script* This ini setting needs to be [changed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) in `php.ini` or `httpd.conf` ***only***.