# Codeigniter Google Recaptcha Form Validation not working in server

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

I have used Google Recaptcha Form Validation in one of the pages . The code works properly in local computer. I uploaded same code in the server, It gives following error in the server.
[image]
I checked php.ini file for allow_url_fopen value and the value is true. My  working code is:

```
$secret ="sercret key";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$rsp = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip$ip");

$arr = json_decode($rsp , true);
```

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36953802/2275490

Comment: double check your secret and token keys on backend and frontend.

Comment: i have checked frontend and backend  secret token keys and both are correct also allow_url_fopen=on in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i am late replying to this. But It is ok i can probably assist those who need my help.

There are 2 methods to solve this.

Method 1:
(I don't really recommend this even when you can fid this from the YouTube)

```
$secret ="sercret key";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$rsp = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? 
secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
$arr = json_decode($rsp , true);
```

Method 2:
A way better method is to use cURL. Here is the code

```
$secret ="sercret key";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$rsp = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? 
secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip;


        $ch = curl_init();   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rsp);   
        $apiresponse = curl_exec($ch);
        $apiresponse = json_decode($apiresponse,true);
```