# 500 Error: https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 when using file_get_contents()

Tags: php, laravel, file-get-contents

I am trying to display youtube videos on a website using API. In order to fetch data from youtube I am using file_get_contents and to decode the received data, I am using json_decode() but none of the functions are working. When I write the following function:

```
file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.'')
```

I get 500 error. Why am I getting internal server error?

And, in the error log file I am getting this

> [2020-01-24 12:32:20] production.ERROR: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 (View: /home/project/project_laravel/resources/views/index.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 (View: /home/project/project_laravel/resources/views/index.blade.php) at /home/project/project_laravel/storage/framework/views/2ef7c353b55ce1b10f018d5d4c745d8de5c15831.php:91, ErrorException(code: 0): file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 at /home/project/project_laravel/storage/framework/views/2ef7c353b55ce1b10f018d5d4c745d8de5c15831.php:91)
>   [stacktrace]

During the research I have tried this answer on StackOverflow [Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952204/warning-file-get-contents-https-wrapper-is-disabled-in-the-server-configu) where the user has suggested us to enable allow_url_fopen, but, there is no allow_url_fopen=0 in my php.ini. And even after adding 
`allow_url_fopen = 1` and
`allow_url_include = 1` 
I still get this error.

Comment: plz post the log error msg.

Comment: Please edit your post and Include the error message

Comment: @TsaiKoga I am getting 500 error page.

Comment: yes, so you need to post the error msg. try to find it in storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: You can use iframe to display youtube video on webpage.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I want to display top 10 videos dynamically.

Comment: @Alisha if you have all the urls of top 10 videos, you can send it to view and display using iframe or using HTML5 `<object>` tag.

Comment: @Alisha Have you tried the sample code in api documentation, that will be easier to get into this I guess. Instead of using flie_get_contents, you can use `Google_Service_Youtue` https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22contentDetails%22%2C%22chart%22%3A%22mostPopular%22%7D and get the urls and if you have urls you can display them using simple HTML.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling allow_url_fopen in php.ini according to this answer [Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952204/warning-file-get-contents-https-wrapper-is-disabled-in-the-server-configu) did not helped me.

When I searched solution for this question again I found this article Enabling [allow_url_fopen](https://chemicloud.com/kb/article/how-to-enable-or-disable-allow_url_fopen-in-cpanel/)

However, since I am using a shared hosting, the support team said to me that this function in php posses security risk, and they do not enable this function in shared server environment and it could only be enabled at my own risk when I am running on vps servers.

So in order to fetch YouTube data via API I had to use cURL function and it worked for me.

Comment: I have got the same issue and when I use cURL it gives me cURL error. The error is like that Curl error: Failed to connect to 66.45.237.70 port 80 after 15028 ms: Couldn't connect to server