# file_get_contents() failed to open stream

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, error-handling, file-get-contents

I am trying to integrate Perfect Money API in codeigniter web app which i got from this link https://github.com/AyubIRZ/PerfectMoneyAPI. It worked completey fine on local server but when uploaded website to live server i began to get error which says `Message: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0` I have searched for it and I couldn't find any solution. Any suggestions what should I do to solve this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: file\_get\_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952204/warning-file-get-contents-https-wrapper-is-disabled-in-the-server-configu)

Answer (score 1):

In `php.ini` you must set `allow_url_fopen = On`.

Comment: where can i find this php.ini in cpanel

Comment: Depends on version, check `/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.ini`. A restart is necessary.