# OpenCart website is showing fatal errors when trying to load

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to open my website, but it is giving errors:

```
Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server
configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/index.php on line 18
 
Warning: require_once(http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/startup.php):
failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in
/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/index.php on line 18

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/startup.php'
(include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/index.php on line 18
```

Server details:
server Name :bakersstore.in/baker
files reside in the baker folder

My frontend config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://bakersstore.in/baker/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/upload/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'agsolgel_bakers');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'ags@AGS@123');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'agsolgel_bakers_store');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

My admin config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'http://bakersstore.in/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'agsolgel_bakers');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'ags@AGS@123');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'agsolgel_bakers_store');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Comment: **Notice**: becarefull for posting such private things like a Mysql username/password in this public website

Comment: Pretty sure that all of those constants starting with `DIR_` probably want to contain local file system paths, and not URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) for the option `allow_url_fopen` from the config file php.ini:

> This option allows the use of URL-aware fopen wrappers with the
> following functions: include, include_once, require, require_once.

and seems that your config is disable that, so edit the php.ini file and enable using below code. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36953802/8010101)

```
allow_url_include = 1 //0 for Off and 1 for On Flag
```

Answer (score 0):

In your configs replace all `DIR_` form URL `http://bakersstore.in/baker/` to your server path `/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/`

Like this. config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://bakersstore.in/baker/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/upload/');

//DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'baker');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'agsolgel_bakers_store');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Admin config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://bakersstore.in/baker/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/agsolgel/public_html/bakersstore.in/baker/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'baker');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'agsolgel_bakers_store');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```