# Facebook Api - saving profile image

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to safe the Profile img from facebook API. This code will get the url/downloadlink but now I want it to save it somewhere on the server so I can get it out of the database and display it somewhere. I thought I might need to use `php copy` function but I am not sure. I also already googled it but that are older versions of the facebook API.

```
$oAuth2Client = $FB->getOAuth2Client();
if (!$accessToken->isLongLived())
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);

$response = $FB->get("/me?fields=id, first_name, last_name, email,gender,link, birthday,picture.type(large)", $accessToken);
$userData = $response->getDecodedBody();

$fb_foto_url = $userData['picture']['data']['url']; 

$voornaam= $app->get_klant_fb($userData['first_name']);
$_SESSION['voornaam'] = $userData['first_name'];
$_SESSION['achternaam'] = $userData['last_name'];

$fb_fotoUrl = $app->saving_fb_foto($userData['picture']['data']['url']);

//data ophalen
$klant= $app->get_klant_fb($userData['id']);
if($klant['id'] > 0) {
    //sessie klant zetten
    $_SESSION['klant_id'] = $klant['id'];
} else {
    //klant aanmaken
    unset($query);
    $query['oauth_uid']     = $userData['id'];
    $query['ledenpagina_id']= $_SESSION['ledenpagina_id'];
    $query['voornaam']      = $userData['first_name'];
    $query['achternaam']    = $userData['last_name'];
    $query['emailadres']    = $userData['email'];
    $query['geboortedatum'] = $userData['birthday'];
    $query['gender']        = $userData['gender']; 
    $query['link']          = $userData['link'];
    $query['foto']          = $userData['picture']['data']['url'];

    $app->insert_query('klanten', $query);

    $klant= $app->get_klant_fb($userData['id']);
    if($klant['id'] > 0) {
        $_SESSION['klant_id'] = $klant['id'];  
    }
}
```

Comment: _“I also already googled it but that are older versions of the facebook API”_ - that has very little to do with it ... You seem to have the URL of the profile picture already? So basically what’s left, is to get the content of a URL with PHP and write it to a file - and that is something you should be able to research, without any connection to a specific API.

Comment: You can use file_get_contents() for ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26350397/2752871

Comment: @CBroe Ill get an url which when I click on it wil download the picture to my computer, Now I need that to go the the server. But how?

Comment: _“But how? ”_ - please do basic research before asking stuff like that! Typing for example “php store image from url to server” into Google gives you lots of results already.

Comment: @CBroe I tried this: `$fb_foto_url = $userData['picture']['data']['url']; 
    copy($fb_foto_url ,'assets/images/profielfotos');` but I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Well for starters, `copy` expects a path including file name for the first two parameters. `assets/images/profielfotos` looks more like it might be an already existing folder …

Comment: @CBroe It is. I need `$fb_foto_url ` to post its value in that folder.

Comment: Well you have to supply a file name, copy does not use the original file name (if any) automatically.