# Trouble in getting fb user's profile image

Tags: php, facebook, user-profile

I want to place user's profile pic on another image, I tried following code to retrieve user profile pic

```
$url='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/picture?type=large';
$userpic = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
imagejpeg($userpic, "xyz.jpg", 100);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: Cannot read image data in /home/a3111484/public_html/fb/index.php
```

I also tried `file_get_contents()` but in that case just an empty jpg file gets created.

please help me figure out the problem.

I tried cURL way also, but got this error:

```
Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /home/a3111484/public_html/fb/index.php on line 31
```

Comment: Has that code been simplified? Line 2 defines `$userpic`, but line 3 uses `$mainphoto`. Also, since no modifications are being made between those two lines, why do you need to use `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagejpeg` rather than just downloading the raw data? Or, for that matter, hot-linking to the facebook-hosted image?

Comment: @IMSoP I beg your pardon, I've now updated the code. Actually I need to modify image, as this way it's not working I tried to download image using file_get_contents() but it retrieves nothing.

Comment: You can get help from below link.
[CLICK HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429964/how-to-save-users-profile-pic-in-facebook-using-php

Comment: Ah, OK. Does `file_get_contents()` return any data (try `echo strlen(file_get_contents($url));`)? Note that this method of downloading data relies on the PHP setting `allow_url_fopen` (http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen), which may be disabled on your server. If that is the case, you'll need to try another method, such as CURL (http://php.net/curl)

Comment: @IMSoP Nothing, echo strlen(file_get_contents($url)); returned 0

Comment: Aha; the mention in your latest edit of "when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set" is telling. These are pretty harsh restrictions that hosts can set on what your PHP is allowed to do, and are likely to mean many of the examples you find online won't work. Consider moving to a less restrictive host (or lobbying yours to implement a more enlightened PHP installation).

Comment: @IMSoP I must consider switching host, thanks for all your help

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Safe mode has been deprecated in v5.3 and removed entirely in v5.4. If your host is using either of these, they shouldn't have safe mode enabled. If they're still on v5.2, you definitely need to be switching hosts, because 5.2 is not supported, and I wouldn't trust a web host that only offers an unsupported version of such critical software.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you need:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$q.'
   /picture?type=large'));
Header( "Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

This lives on my site as `facebook_img.php`.

I use it to add an image to a page using code like this:

```
printf('<meta property="og:image" content="/path/to/facebook_img.php?q=%s" />', $fb_user_id);
```

@IMSoP: You need to do something convoluted like this because a `id/picture` API endpoint returns a 301 redirect to the photo url.

Comment: Not sure why a 301 redirect would make any difference to this. A browser should be quite happy to render an image that is served to it via a redirect.

Comment: Updated my example. Yes, the browser is happy to display that in an <img> tag, but you can't use a 301 redirect for metadata.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. A case of one Facebook API (the "og:" metadata tags) being defeated by another (the easy profile image lookup URLs)!